# Find the general solution to $\sin(4x)-\cos(x)=0$

Tags: trigonometry

> > Question: Find the general solution to $\sin(4x)-\cos(x)=0$

---

My attempt:

$$ \sin(4x)-\cos(x)=0$$

$$ \Leftrightarrow \sin(4x) = \cos(x) $$

$$ \Leftrightarrow \sin(4x) = \sin( \frac{\pi}{2} -x)$$

From another post I learnt that you can equate $\sin(x) = \sin(y)$ on 2 conditions so applying it here:

$$ \Leftrightarrow 4x = \frac{\pi}{2} -x + 2 \pi n$$

and 
$$ \Leftrightarrow4x = \pi - (\frac{\pi}{2} -x)+ 2 \pi n$$

Solving both for $x$

$$ x = \frac{\pi}{10}  + \frac{2\pi n }{5}$$

$$ x = \frac{\pi}{6}  + \frac{2\pi n }{3}$$

However I checked Wolfram alpha and they have different solutions?

[image]

Am I correct or not?

Comment: @Edi No I do not.

Comment: You can't directly compare trig functions of different periods this way:  you will have to find an expression for $  \ \sin 4x \ $ in terms of $ \ \sin x \ $ and $ \ \cos x \ $ using the double-angle formula for sine twice and other trig identities as well.

Comment: Why does it work for this case http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1698332/298824

Comment: You shouldn't vandalize your post by erasing the work you did on the problem.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig oops that was an accident

Comment: Your solution is correct.  If you click on more roots on Wolfram alpha, you will find the solutions $\frac{\pi}{6} + 2n\pi$ and $\frac{5\pi}{6} + 2n\pi$.  Together with the solution $n\pi - \frac{\pi}{2}$, those solutions are the solutions to the equation $x = \frac{\pi}{6} + \frac{2n\pi}{3}$.  The other solutions listed above together with $x = n\pi - \frac{\pi}{2}$ are equivalent to your solution $x = \frac{\pi}{5} + \frac{2n\pi}{5}$.  See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1055168/if-cos-theta-cos-alpha-what-can-we-conclude-about-theta-alpha/1055200#1055200) explanation.

Comment: Everything is fine. Your solution is quite nice and compact.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig thank you , your explanation was nice

Comment: @AndréNicolas thank you for the confirmation, is there a trick to know if solutions overlap or not?

Comment: Your solutions do not overlap.

Comment: @AndréNicolas no I meant with wolfram alpha's solutions 1

Comment: At one point I was writing up an answer to the effect they are the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\sin(4x)−\cos(x)=0$

$2\sin(2x)\cos(2x)-\cos(x)=0$

$4\sin(x)\cos(x)(1-2\sin^2(x))-\cos(x)=0$

One possible solution is $\cos(x)=0$

$4\sin(x)(1-2\sin^2(x))=1$

$8\sin^3(x)-4\sin(x)+1=0$

Now, let $\sin(x)=m$ and solve the resulting cubic...

Comment: Observe that  $$4\sin x\cos x(1 - 2\sin^2x)  - \cos x =  \cos x(4\sin x - 8\sin^3x - 1)$$ so we obtain $\cos x = 0$ or $4\sin x - 8\sin^3x - 1 = 0$.  If we multiply the cubic polynomial in sine by $-1$, we obtain $8\sin^3x - 4\sin x \color{red}{+} 1 = 0$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Right, of course, sorry about the typo.